# html form search in Array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to be able to search in an array of objects.
I have a HTML-for:

```
<form action="#" id="filters">

        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search"/>
    </form>
    <div id="searchresult"></div>
```

I have no idea how to begin, can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 
array.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

One way would be to attach an `input` event to the input field so that whenever there's a change in the input field value, you can get the input field value and then use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the `meals` array based on the value of the input field. Finally, you can display the filtered results in the `searchresult div`.

```js
const meals = [
   {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Strawberry Salad with Poppy Seed Dressing',
     img: 'Strawberry-Salad-with-Poppy-Seed-Dressing.jpg',
     book: 1
   },

   {
     id: 2,
     title: 'Cashew Turkey Salad Sandwiches',
     img: 'turkey-sandwich.jpg',
     book: 2
   }
];

const searchField = document.querySelector('#search');
const searchResultsContainer = document.querySelector('#searchresult');

searchField.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  
  // if input field is empty, clear the search results
  if(e.target.value === '') {
     searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
     return;
  }
  
  // filter the meals array
  const searchResults = meals.filter(meal => {
      return meal.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  });
  
  // before displaying the search results, clear the search results div
  searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
  
  // display the titles of the meal objects that include the text entered in input field
  searchResults.forEach((element, index) => {
     const p = document.createElement('p');
     p.textContent = (index + 1) + '. ' + element.title;
     searchResultsContainer.appendChild(p);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="filters">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search"/>
</form>
<div id="searchresult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without revealing complete code and say, here you are, I will try to navigate you so you can come up with your own solution instead. follow roughly these steps:

- listen to your search input = When you type on keyboard you want to
  update search results. You can listen for [onkeypress,
  onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) or simple [input change](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)
  other events inside the input
- when key is pressed you need to check the new value inside input = You can do that by [checking it's value property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp).
- lastly, you want to get only objects from the list conforming to the
  search value = there are sleek JS functions to [filter out items in an
  array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) or you can do it in standard for loop

Hope that gives you some idea about what to do. This might be a [source of inspiration](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) for you